# Using F-score as a performance measure when doing cross-validation for imbalanced data

Tags: cross-validation

I have 200 points for the first class and 400 points for the second. I'm using cross-validation with f-score as a performance measure. Due to imbalance data, is it ok to do this without over-sampling, undersampling or any other techniques to handle this imbalance in the data? Since F-score accounts for the imbalance data, I don't see a problem doing this.

Comment: That's not really imbalanced.  Imbalanced is 0.01% or 0.001% of the rare class.  You just have regular, everyday data, and do not need any any special techniques besides working with probabilities, and tuning a classification threshold carefully (if you really even need to).  In particular, I would advise against over or under sampling.

Comment: @MatthewDrury so why when I randomly shuffled the labels, I got similar f-score for the original (true) labels (using cross-validation)? What are explanations except that the classifier is overfitting due to this "imbalance" data?

Comment: I don't follow.  That sounds like *under* fitting, if anything.  What kind of model are you fitting?  Why are you not evaluating with a proper scoring rule like log-loss?  Whatever the issue, a 1/2 ratio of class proportions is not an issue for almost all machine learning models.